# Foreign-origin indexedDB cache?

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, indexeddb, service-worker, same-origin-policy

**Short version**

Is it possible to create an indexedDB under the foreign origin of a script, imported through importScripts()?

**Long version**

My goal is to be able to share (indexedDB-) cached resources across multiple applications through a shared service-worker.

For example:

```
//hosted on https://site1.com

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker1.js', {scope: ' '}).then(function() {})
    }
  </script>
```

```
//serviceWorker1.js

importScripts("https://serviceWorker.com/sw.js");
```

---

```
//hosted on https://site2.com

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker2.js', {scope: ' '}).then(function() {})
    }
  </script>
```

```
//serviceWorker2.js

importScripts("https://serviceWorker.com/sw.js");
```

---

```
//https://serviceWorker.com/sw.js

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // I wanted indexedDB here to be scoped under https://serviceWorker.com, 
  // not https://site1.com or https://site2.com
});
```

I have figured out the following:

- Service workers need to be called over https (or localhost) from the same origin
- A "foreign origin" service-worker can be loaded into your current origin by using importScripts("https://serviceWorker.com/sw.js") in the (same-origin) loaded service-worker script file.
- Browsers sandbox indexedDB databases based on a so-called "same-origin policy", which dictates only scripts from the same origin tuple (scheme, url, port) may operate on the same cache. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)
- importScripts() imports one or more scripts into the worker's scope.

I want to know the following:

Is it possible to create an indexedDB under the foreign origin of a script, imported through importScripts()?

If so, how? If not, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use iframe and postmessage to communicate between different domains.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Where the bytes making up a script are loaded from does not affect the permissions granted to the script for accessing resources. For example, in a page loaded from http://example.com, a script loaded from http://example.org:1234 has exactly the same permissions as a script loaded from http://example.com; it can't fetch and inspect arbitrary resources from http://example.org:1234 any more than script loaded from http://example.com can. This applies to storage APIs as well and other origin-scoped functionality of the web platform.

The usual work-around is to have the page host an iframe from the second origin. The frames can use postMessage() to communicate; the hosted frame restricts communication to an origin it trusts. Typically, this communication would be wrapped in a proxy of some sort so that the hosting page just sees a async storage API.